# Reaction-diffusion Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

How do I solve this reaction-diffusion Cauchy problem?

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
u_{t} - \kappa u_{xx} +ru=0 & \quad \mbox{$x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0$,}\\
\quad u(x,0) = \phi(x), \end{array} \right. $$

where $\kappa > 0$ and $r>0$ are constants.

So I defined $v(x,t)=e^{rt}u(x,t)$. How do I show that $v$ solves the heat equation with the same initial condition $\phi$? Then I think I find $u$ by solving the heat equation for $v$? But how do I go about this as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the given equation

$u_t -\kappa u_{xx} + ru \tag 1$

may be re-arranged to read

$\kappa u_{xx} = u_t + ru; \tag 2$

if we set

$v = e^{rt}u; \tag 3$

then

$v_t = re^{rt}u + e^{rt}u_t, \tag 4$

and also

$v_{xx} = e^{rt}u_{xx}; \tag 5$

thus by (2) and (4),

$\kappa v_{xx} = \kappa e^{rt} u_{xx} = e^{rt}u_t + e^{rt}ru = v_t; \tag 6$

furthermore,

$v(x, 0) = e^{r(0)}u(x, 0) = u(x, 0) = \phi(x); \tag 7$

we see in (6) and (7) that $v(x,t)$ solves the heat equation with the same initial conditions as $u$.

As far as solving the equation

$v_t = \kappa v_{xx}, \; v(x, 0) = \phi(x) \tag 9$

is concerned, there are many techniques available; it is a big topic, covered in many texts on partial differential equations, as well as on many web sites.  A good place to start is these wikipedia articles on [the heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) and [the heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel).  They probably give better information on how to solve (9) than I could here.